# How can I successfully make call to Twilio and get the audio stream into my app?

Tags: aws-lambda, websocket, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Now Whenever I make the call it goes through but then it says there's an error Goodbye!.
I have set the webhook for the web sockets on Twilio. The endpoint for the outgoing call is my-end-point/ and the endpont for the statuscallback is my-end-point/record. I'm using a websockets in SST environment. I want to use the Twilio event; connected, start, media, stop so the call can be properly handled and return the stream.

I tried with the code below but it doesn't work properly. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

```
import { ApiHandler } from "sst/node/api";
import Twilio from "twilio";
import WebSocket from "ws";

export const handler = ApiHandler(async (event) => {
  const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
  const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;

  // Create an authenticated Twilio Client instance
  const client = Twilio(accountSid, authToken);

  const ws = new WebSocket(
    "wss://4pi3fywj9u.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/JosephAdeabah"
  );

  ws.on("open", function connectionOpen() {
    console.log("WebSocket connection opened");
  });

  ws.on("message", async function incoming(rawMessage) {
    const message = rawMessage.toString(); // Convert the raw data to a string

    console.log("Received message:", message);

    const msg = JSON.parse(message);

    let call;

    switch (msg.event) {
      case "connected":
        // Handle the "connected" event
        console.log("Call connected");
        break;
      case "start":
        // Handle the "start" event
        try {
          call = await client.calls.create({
            url: "https://0sbfdfxbb0.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
            to: "+13613092711", // your phone number
            from: "+233542150637", // a valid Twilio number
            statusCallback:
              "https://0sbfdfxbb0.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/record",
            statusCallbackEvent: [
              "initiated",
              "ringing",
              "answered",
              "completed",
            ],
          });

          // Success, return message SID
          console.log(`Call SID:`, call.sid);
          return call;
        } catch (error) {
          // Error, return error object
          console.error(`Error sending call: ${error}`);
        }
        break;
      case "media":
        if (call) {
          console.log("Received media for call:", msg.payload.call_sid);
          // Perform media handling for the call
          // ...
        }
        break;
      case "stop":
        // Handle the "stop" event
        console.log("Call stopped");
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the Twilio error log in the console (the Twilio website) and it will tell you information about the reason for the error.

Comment: @jassent thanks, I found the reason. because I was running it in the SST environment, I didn't need to use the node JS websocket. It was what was preventing the code to execute properly